# JSLint doesn't like ++ incrementers. What's a replacement for ++i?

Tags: javascript, increment, jslint

I'm pushing a script through JSLint like rocks through a food mill. Slowly, and with a lot of grinding.

I have updated all the i++ incrementers to i+=1. What should I do in the case of ++i, as in, b = ++i ?

Comment: `i += 1; b = i`, innit?

Comment: Changing `++i` to `(i += 1)` will work, but changing `i++` to that *won't* always work.

Comment: You should replace jslint, not incrementers

Comment: this is probably the least helpful of lint's suggestions; ++i doesn't look like buggy code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preincrement (`++i`) adds one to the value of `i`, then returns `i`.  You get the same effect if you put them on separate lines.

```
i += 1;
b = i;
```